# LinqPad Member Description ("Quick Info") NOT Show up

Tags: linqpad

I got trouble on Member Description show up.

For example, I have two laptops.

Laptop A, I install ".NET Framework 4 (Standalone Installer)" version.

I type code like follow:

```
void Main()
{
    var q = {"A", "B", "C"};
    q.
}
```

When typing the "." , there is a member list show up, When I move my cursor to member "Aggregate", it should show up a member description like "Applies an accumulator function over a sequence.". Unfortunately, this importance description NOT SHOW UP.

Laptop B, I install ".NET Framework 4 (Standalone Installer)" + Visual studio 2010 Express. The member description show up without any problem.

So, How to fix the problem on Laptop A without install visual studio. Laptop A has 1 G Ram, I don't want install heavy things like visual studio, but I need the method description.

Please give me step by step fix instruction, it will be great appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the .NET Framework without Visual Studio means that you don't end up with the reference assembly folders that contain the XML documentation files that describe what each type and member does.

So yes, you'll get autocompletion listings, but you won't get the descriptions of what each member does.

There are a couple of ways to work around this (without installing Visual Studio). The first is to install the [Framework 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279). I've not tried installing this, but I strongly suspect it would contain the full reference assemblies.

The other is to copy over the reference assemblies from your machine with VS installed to the other computer. The reference assemblies for Framework 4.0 are in this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0
```

Comment: Hi Joe, I am so exciting I can get directly reply from you. I am you super fans.

Comment: After I install Framework 4 SDK, laptop A works perfect. Many Thanks!